# PHP Foreach loop ending

Tags: php, foreach

How do I make the final foreach instance end without the , character? As it stands every instance of $var2 is followed by a , character. Code to follow, thanks in advance.

```
foreach($tags as $var1 => $var2) {
    if($_SESSION[$var1]!="off")
    {
    include($var2);
    echo",";    
    //needs to include no , character on the last instance.
    }
    else
    {
    echo $var1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question seems unclear to me. What are you exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your foreach, change the `echo ",";` to following:

```
if (end($tags) != $var2) {
  echo ",";
}
```

Doing this will check if you are in the last index by comparing the current index to the last index of the `$tags` array. Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to see the PHP wiki on the `end()` function.

Answer (score 0):

First insert all your echo's into string.
Then delete final instance of "," with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\,$/', '', $str);
```

Another way is with a counter:

```
$len = count($tags);  
$iter = 0;
foreach($tags as $var1 => $var2) {
        if($_SESSION[$var1]!="off")
        {
        include($var2);
        if($iter != $len-1)
          echo",";    
        //needs to include no , character on the last instance.
        }
        else
        {
        echo $var1;
        }
      $iter++;
    }
```

Another way with end() function

```
foreach($tags as $var1 => $var2) {
    if($_SESSION[$var1]!="off")
    {
    include($var2);
    if (end($tags) != $var2) {
       echo",";    
    //needs to include no , character on the last instance.
    }
    else
    {
    echo $var1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it works fine, preg_replace is a little on heavy for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you retrieve the last element with [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) and gets is key with [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) that you compare with the current key:

```
foreach($tags as $var1 => $var2) {
    if($_SESSION[$var1]!="off")
    {
        include($var2);
        //needs to include no , character on the last instance.
        if(key(end($tags)) !== $var1)
        {
            echo",";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $var1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wil help you

```
 $result = '';
    foreach($tags as $var1 =>$var2) {
        $result .= $var2.',';
    }
    $result = rtrim($result,',');
    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `end()` function to get the last item:

```
$last_item = end(array_keys($tags));
foreach($tags as $var1 => $var2) {
    if($_SESSION[$var1]!="off") {
    {
        include($var2);
        if($var1 !== $last_key) {
            echo",";    
        }
    //needs to include no , character on the last instance.
    }
    else
    {
        echo $var1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to check the last element and echo comma(,)

```
$numItems = count($tags );
$i = 0;
foreach($tags  as $var1 =>$var2) {
if($_SESSION[$var1]!="off")
{
include($var2);
if(++$i != $numItems) {
echo ",";
}
}
else
{
echo $var1;
}
}
```